# moderncv LaTeX error: File `suffix.sty' not found

Tags: errors, moderncv

I'm a LaTeX noob and i'm trying to create CV with `moderncv` package. I installed it via Tex Live Utility and then tried to start creating my own cv with `cv_7.tex` template (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter) with TeXWorks.

When run the template I get this:

```
(./moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xargs/xargs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(./moderncvcompatibility.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `suffix.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

I tried to find this suffix style from TexLive Utility but I can't seem to find it! Any solutions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: Mac OS 10.5.8 and I'm not sure how I can copy files to my TeXMF-tree :embarrassed: :s

Answer (score 15):

You need to either:

- install the [`bigfoot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) package (`suffix.sty` is part of that package; there is no standalone `suffix` package), or
- update your `moderncv` package (versions newer than 1.3.0 don't rely on `suffix.sty` anymore).

Comment: bigfoot package solved my problem! Thanks a ton!